# SonataAdminBundle set NULL $formMapper

Tags: symfony, null, sonata-admin

how to set field NULL if nothing was writen in the input ?

I would like to have a checkbox to NULLIFY the field. (even if the field is blank, need NULL in mysql field)

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a valid way to accomplish that in symfony2 and sonata-admin

specifically used for a boolean field with nullable = true
(nb: mysql field boolean in symfony2 are actually tinyint:1)

once it is edited, such a field would normally pass to true but if you intercept the request and evaluate the value of a given field you can modify it like this:

in your admin class, assuming the property of the object is *property*

```
public function prePersist($object)
{
    if (in_array($object->getProperty(), array(NULL, '', '3',)))
        $object->setProperty(NULL);
}

public function preUpdate($object)
{
    if (in_array($object->getProperty(), array(NULL, '', '3',)))
        $object->setProperty(NULL);
}
```

> the number 3 is what I implemented in my case for a select where null is needed

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('property', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                '3' => 'Yes and No',
                '0' => 'No',
                '1' => 'Yes',
            ),
            'empty_value' => false,// unset this and empty would work also
            'required' => false,
        ))
    //    ->add('property', null, array('required' => false))// checkbox if bool
    ;
}
```

Hope that helps!
Cheers,
Vince

Comment: you do this for all your property ? i don't understand what is $object

Comment: actually, for the ones you need to... $object is really the entity your are administrating... it can be for instance an article with a published property. (where maybe the flag in between, neither 0 nor 1, would signify it is in a validating state...)
In such a case, the script would look like that:
$object->getPublished() and $object->setPublished(NULL)